# read sql schema in sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I am using some SQL schema in my database,

```
CoursesProperties.tbl_Countries
CoursesProperties.tbl_Rating
```

In my .net application, I am using a `SqlDataSourse` to fill a GridView straight forward

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceLocations" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TrainingConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT CountryE FROM [CourseProperties.tbl_Countries]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I run my application I am getting this error:

> Invalid object name 'CourseProperties.tbl_Countries'.

Even if I remove the schema I getting error

> Invalid object name 'tbl_Countries'.

I thought about removing the schema from the database, but I thought let's first seek help from the experts.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The square brackets should be:

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT CountryE FROM [CourseProperties].[tbl_Countries]"
```

or omit them completely:

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT CountryE FROM CourseProperties.tbl_Countries"
```

but not around the schema *AND* table name

[Square brackets are required only if you use spaces, keywords or special characters in column names (or identifiers), which you should try to avoid.]